# Geodjango: Change PolygonField to MultiPolygonField with exisiting data using a migration

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration, geodjango

I have a model with a `PolygonField`, which had dozens of rows. I am trying to change the field to `MultiPolygonField`, but data is still in `polygon` mode. How can I convert all existing data to the new type?

`models.py`:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("region")
        verbose_name_plural = _("regions")

    polygon = models.PolygonField(_("polygon"))  # <== this is going to be MultiPolygon
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=100)
```

Comment: You say that you have a Table with a column of type "Polygon" which has dozens of "Fields". A column doesn't have fields, tables have fields. I think most people would assume that "fields" and "columns" are referring to the same thing, but you seem to be using them to describe different things. Are you meaning to Say you have a Table named Polygon with dozens of Fields? This question is a bit confusing to me. Can you post your models, what your trying to change, any relevant code, what results you are expecting, and what results you are actually getting?

Comment: added my model code @NathanSmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option 1: Use SQL

Assuming you are using postgis, the following SQL can convert your data by using [`ST_Multi`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html):

```
ALTER TABLE myapp_region
    ALTER COLUMN polygon TYPE geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)
    USING ST_Multi(polygon);
```

Do not execute this directly, instead run `makemigrations` which will create a new migration (for example: `myapp/migrations/0006_yyyyyyyy.py`) similar to:

```
import django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0005_zzzzzzzzzzzzz'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='region',
            name='polygon',
            field=django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326),
        ),
    ]
```

Encapsulate your `AlterField` opertaions with a `RunSQL` operation like this:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(
        "ALTER TABLE myapp_region ALTER COLUMN polygon type geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326) using ST_Multi(polygon);",
        state_operations=[
            migrations.AlterField(
                model_name='region',
                name='polygon',
                field=django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.MultiPolygonField(
                    srid=4326),
            ),
        ],
    )
]
```

and now run your migration.

### Option 2: Data Migrations

- Create a new `geom = models.MultiPolygonField(null=True)` field next to your current field.
- Create and run a migration to add the new multipolygon field.
- Create a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) and use [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) to copy your data:

  ```
  for o in Region.objects.all():
      o.geom = MultiPolygon([o.polygon])
      o.save()
  ```

  (Untested: You might be able to use `Region.objects.update()` instead)
- In `models.py`, delete the original field and remove `null=True`; create a migration.
- Optional: rename `geom` to `polygon` with another migration.

Comment: your second solution encounters this error:  Cannot set Region SpatialProxy (MULTIPOLYGON) with value of type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.polygon.Polygon'>

Comment: but the first one worked..such a brilliant answer, tnx a million

Comment: Regarding the "Cannot set Region SpatialProxy" error, make sre to import MultiPolygon from `django.contrib.gis.geos`.